# ReplaceWith jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("#file-upload").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        $('#cancel-image-upload').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel-upload-button" style="margin-right:15px;">cancel</button>');
    }
    else
        $("#image-preview").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/200x150");
});


$('#cancel-upload-button').click(function () {
        $("#file-upload").replaceWith('<input type="file" id="file-upload" name="file" accept="image/*">');
    });
```

What this code does is to display cancel button after file has been chosen, and the button should be able to delete it when clicked. I tried the code above but it didn't work for some reason. Why and how can I fix it? thanks!

Comment: Like you have used before, did you try directly using `.html` than `replaceWith`.

Comment: @j809 Yeah, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#cancel-upload-button', function () {
    $("#file-upload").replaceWith('<input type="file" id="file-upload" name="file" accept="image/*">');
});
```

You need a live binding in order to keep the event on the cancel button, since you're removing it from the DOM in the #file-upload change() callback.

Comment: The same goes of course for the bindings of #file-upload, since it gets replaced dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Add #cancel-upload-button's click handler just after adding the control ie inside the if loop.